# Error in passing String from HTML form to node js

Tags: html, node.js

I am working on a school project where I have to take a SQL query as an input and send it to node js code to process the query. But I could not do that. I am getting error when I submit my query. The console says:

```
Server started listening...
url.js:143
throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'url', 'string', url);
^
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type object.
```

```
function operation(){
    var x = document.getElementById("num1");
    var text="";
    text = x.elements[0].value;
    document.getElementById("yoo").innerHTML = typeof text;  //line 1
    location.href = "http://localhost:3306" + "?number1=" + text;
}
```

But when I check it with line 1, on HTML page it says that variable text is a STRING....

how should I rectify it?

node js code as follows:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var mysql = require('mysql');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
console.log("Server started listening...");
var up = url.parse(request, true).query;
var q = up.number1;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "ebookshop"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query(q, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
response.end();
}).listen(3306);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the URL String to `url.parse` instead of the request object. Use `request.url`. Node.JS documentation https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost